# Can yarp transform a request with information from the request header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

I am trying to make a reverse proxy in my application. In my case, I need the path to be transformed to include information stored in the request header.

```cs
"ReverseProxy": {
"Routes": {
  "MyRoute": {
    "ClusterId": "MyCluster",
    "AuthorizationPolicy": "DefaultPolicy",
    "Match": {
      "Path": "/api/{**remainder}"
    },
    "Transforms": [
      { "PathPattern": "/api/{item}/{**remainder}" },
      {
        "ResponseHeader": "Source",
        "Append": "YARP",
        "When": "Success"
      }
    ]
  }
},
"Clusters": {
  "MyCluster": {
    "Destinations": {
      "MyCluster/destination": {
        "Address": "https://myAddress.com/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to create a custom transform:

```
services.AddReverseProxy()
.LoadFromConfig(_configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"))
.AddTransforms(builderContext =>
{
    builderContext.RequestTransforms.Add(new Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms.RequestTransform()
    {

    }
});
```

Can I replace {item} with the information included in the request header?

Comment: You can try creating a [custom transform](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/transforms.html#addrequesttransform) with [AddRequestTransform](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/api/Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms.TransformBuilderContextFuncExtensions.html#Yarp_ReverseProxy_Transforms_TransformBuilderContextFuncExtensions_AddRequestTransform_Yarp_ReverseProxy_Transforms_Builder_TransformBuilderContext_System_Func_Yarp_ReverseProxy_Transforms_RequestTransformContext_System_Threading_Tasks_ValueTask__) in code.

Comment: In the transform method you can read the [RequestTransformContext.HttpContext](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/api/Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms.RequestTransformContext.html#Yarp_ReverseProxy_Transforms_RequestTransformContext_HttpContext).Request.Headers collection and calculate a new `Path` value

Comment: I have tried that method and for some reason I do not have the AddRequestTransform method.

Comment: This method was added in YARP 1.1. Which version do you have?

Comment: I have version 1.1.1

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: It seems I need to do builderContext.RequestTransforms.Add

Comment: VS did not automatically recognize I needed Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms

Answer (score 2):

You can create a proxy pipeline middleware.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>    
{
    endpoints.MapReverseProxy(proxyPipeline =>        
    {
        proxyPipeline.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            //You can use context to change request before they are sent.
        });
    });
});
```

Follow [this](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/middleware.html) guide on adding middleware. The placement of UseRouting and UseEndpoints matters when creating middleware for authentication.